# Which is more Efficient to send across a network?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I've had a think about it, and I'm not sure which is better to use in my projects: So I've got a client sending a request to a server to perform a task (like changing a stat, for example), and the server returns a response. Currently it's returning 3/4 `boolean` values (`true,false,false`) depending on the response, where it is successful, an error and not enough funds.

I'm now thinking about which would be more effective to send across a network back to the client, the above method, or a single `string`/`integer` value representing a certain response (*like an error code would*). *I'm not 100% sure*, although I'm guessing it would be the `boolean` values as they're only a bit each, `0/1`, rather than a byte of data. If anyone knows, that would be great, as I'm hoping to make this game the most efficient it can be, within reason.

Thanks for your time, and any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: The protocol must have some sort of information about the type of each value, not just the values themselves, so probably more than three bytes are involved. Anyway, I doubt this difference will ever be noticeable. Focus instead on proper client/server division, any CPU-intensive calculations, and then maybe any large messages.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm guessing that the CPU-heavy stuff needs to go on the server?